# How do I increase the inactivity timeout for Selenium Grid?

Tags: java, selenium, microsoft-edge, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

> The Setup:
>   - A Win7 box running Java Selenium tests which automate a Selenium Grid using the Edge browser (on a local Win10 Virtualbox VM)

If I pause for too long when debugging Selenium tests for Edge, the Edge instance dies and I have to restart the test.

> The hub showed an error of:
>   `key 31b56d50-91eb-4c45-8dda-39cb8da4638a has TIMED OUT due to client inactivity and will be released`

I am assuming that the Edge WebDriver is the culprit here, but am open to other explanations.

Are there any setting that will extend this timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium Grid Node has a [command line parameter](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters) "`-timeout`" which determines how long the browser will remain open if the session is inactive.

e.g. (line breaks are for clarity only)

```
start "2.53.0 node Edge Node" 
      cmd /k 
            java -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" -cp .;* 
                 org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher 
                     -role node 
                     -timeout 6000 
                     -nodeConfig ..\conf\test-node-config-localhub-edge.json
```